# Maven - How to pass partial value in system property variables from POM.xml

Tags: selenium, maven, environment-variables, pom.xml

here below is my `url` variable in pom.xml where i have to append `qa` value in `${evn}` to run in different environment,
i want to pass `env` alone from my `url` tag to pass on run time like below
`mvn clean test -Denv=qa`
my expectation to get url in test is like - https://www.qagoogle.com

```
  <systemPropertyVariables>
    <url>https://www.${env}google.com/</url>
  </systemPropertyVariables>
```

Comment: Please try again formulating this question. It is completely unclear to me.

Comment: @JFabianMeier - hope now the question is clear, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the variable with `-Denv` you also need to add it to `systemPropertyVariables`

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <env></env>
    <url>https://www.${env}google.com/</url>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

and then, you can run `mvn clean test -Denv=qa`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a properties section to your `pom.xml`:

```
    <properties>
        <env>qa</env>
    </properties>
```

Comment: yes i can use this when i pass complete variable, but i want to send partial value in it, like said above